# How to retrieve values post-execution of PL/SQL stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql, return

Im very new to oracle database stuff.   There is a PL/SQL proceedure which someone else wrote and is stored on the database I am accessing.   I want my program to execute it and retrieve the result.   Execution is working.  I cannot retrieve the result however.   Obviously I am not doing it right, but I cannot find the right way in the documentation.

Here is the gist of the stored procedure (with extraneous lines removed)

```
procedure ISDRAWINGVALID(DWGNO_IN in VARCHAR2) is
valid BOOLEAN;
begin
-- do some stuff to see if the drawing is valid
IF <some stuff> THEN
valid := TRUE;
ELSE
valid := FALSE;
END IF;
END ISDRAWINGVALID;
```

My program issues the following commands to the database to execute and retrieve the return.

```
BEGIN ISDRAWINGVALID( <drawingnumber> ); END;
SELECT ISDRAWINGVALID.valid FROM DUAL;
```

The first line works fine, the proceedure executes and has the desired effect. 
The second line returns an error, invalid identifier "ISDRAWINGVALID.valid"

Clearly i am not using the right way to retrieve the value.   Can someone please clue me in?

thanks

Comment: The procedure you posted doesn't return anything.  Once the procedure finishes execution, the local variable goes out of scope.  You can't access it outside the procedure.  If you want the procedure to return something to the caller, the procedure would need to do something like declare an `OUT` parameter.  Depending on what "do some stuff" is, you may want to create a function that returns a `boolean` rather than a procedure.

Comment: You can't return a result from a procedure. You could have an OUT parameter that you set instead of the local variable, and your caller could then look at that. Or you could use a function instead, but Oracle SQL doesn't have a boolean type so you could still only call it from PL/SQL. A function still looks more appropriate, unless the code you haven't shown is modifying any data; but are you stuck with the procedure you already have, which seems a bit pointless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you present the problem, there is no way to get the result.

If you can get the procedure as a function instead, you can call it directly in the select statement.

Otherwise you would have to take a long detour to solve it, involving a result table or a pl/sql package with a result function and a package variable.

The procedure you have there has been made to be called from other pl/sql code - not in a select query.

**EDIT**

I think I might be wrong after all.
In Java you can create a prepared statement with a call, and pick up the return value directly as a result-set.
Check this out and come back with the result: http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/08/13/stored_procedures.html?page=2

Sorry if you are not using Java, I was not able to see what you are using.

Comment: You can't call a function that returns boolean from a select though, as Oracle SQL doesn't have a boolean type. So it would have to return a proxy value; Y/N, 0/1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function and return a NUMBER to be used in SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION ISDRAWINGVALID(DWGNO_IN in VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER
IS
   valid NUMBER;
BEGIN
   IF <some stuff> THEN
      valid := 1;
   ELSE
      valid := 0;
   END IF;
   RETURN valid;
END ISDRAWINGVALID;
```

Use from PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
   valid NUMBER;
BEGIN
   valid := ISDRAWINGVALID( <drawingnumber> );
END;
/
```

Use from SQL:

```
SELECT ISDRAWINGVALID( <drawingnumber> ) FROM DUAL;
```